# Чтение данных из DBF запросом в Java

Tags: java

Используя библиотеку javadbf получилось прочесть данные из dbf и вывести например в консоль их. Но часто бывает нужно вытащить данные из dbf по какому-то условию запросом. Хотел бы узнать поддерживает ли библиотека javadbf такое или нужна библиотека пофункциональнее?

Пока что есть вот такой код

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DBFReader reader = null;
        try {

            reader = new DBFReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\files\\test.DBF")));

            Object[] rowObjects;
            while ((rowObjects = reader.nextRecord()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < rowObjects.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(rowObjects[i] + " ");
                }
            }

        } catch (DBFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            DBFUtils.close(reader);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, такого функционала нет в библиотеках.

Однако вы можете после считывания, в соответствии с вашей структурой классов (если вы конечно размапили в объекты) воспользоваться стримами для фильтрации тех или иных данных.

Если вам нужно именно "поселектить" из DBF, то потребуется некий драйвер который позволит работать с вашим файлом как с базой данных. Насколько я знаю, есть Microsoft dBASE Driver, который вроде бы даже это умеет.

Comment: Мне нужно из кучи записей получить только определенные по условиям. Почитаю про драйвер.

Comment: А не подскажете как ее подключить этот драйвер. У меня ругается на строку Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

Comment: Вероятно вы зависимости какие то потеряли.